Adding dynamicTemplate to google cloud template launch
We use a google cloud function to launch a template via: https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/reference/rest/v1b3/projects.locations.templates/launch
We wanted to add a staging location to the request via the dynamicTemplate with this layout:
DYNAMICTEMPLATE = {"gcsPath" : GCSPATH, "stagingLocation" : "gs://xxx/dataflow/staging"}

request = service.projects().locations().templates().launch(projectId=PROJECT, gcsPath=GCSPATH, body=BODY, location=LOCATION, dynamicTemplate=DYNAMICTEMPLATE)
response = request.execute()

But the logging returns the following error: TypeError: Got an unexpected keyword argument "dynamicTemplate"
Without the dynamicTemplate everything runs without a problem. We also tried to add the dynamicTemplate in the body, but that would not work either.. Does anybody know how to set up the dynamicTemplate?

Hi @Mark Wekking, It appears that this issue has to be investigated further, so if you have a support plan please create a new GCP support Case. Otherwise, you can open a new issue on the issue trackerdescribing your issue
